# A weird bar suddenly started to appear at the bottom of my app after compiling with xCode 7.1

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad, ios7

A weird bar suddenly started to appear at the bottom of my app after compiling with xCode 7.1.
Do you have any idea about what is this bar? Any body can recognise it or give me a direction to check the source of the problem? : 
[screenshot url](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YnBLO.png)

Comment: Looks like the top of the keyboard.

Comment: Thanks man, I solved it after your hint

Comment: If you get a chance, add your own answer to your question and say how you solved it, in case anyone else has this problem in future.

Answer (score 0):

If you're compiling in the Simulator, go to Hardware > Keyboard, and turn off Connect Hardware Keyboard. You can also just hit Cmd-Shift-K to do the same thing.